# Inserting values into Database.mdf C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database

I've been trying to insert values to a `Database.mdf` SQL Server database file via datagridView from a few textboxes before loading them in to a Chart, but first it was returning this error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand' does not contain a definition for
>   'Open' and no extension method 'Open' accepting a first argument of
>   type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand' could be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication6\WindowsFormsApplication6\Form1.cs
>   65 44 WindowsFormsApplication6

But then that error disappeared (without me changing any code, but merely recompiling it) and now this function (i.e; `sendrow()`) is effectively useless, doing absolutely nothing, not even giving an error. I suppose if it managed to write it to database, I could have seen it on datagridView on Form.

```
SqlConnectionStringBuilder csb = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
csb.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication6\WindowsFormsApplication6\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True";

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(csb.ConnectionString))
{ 
    conn.Open();

    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Stocks (Open, High, Low, Close, Day) VALUES (@Open, @High, @Low, @Close, @Day)"))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = conn;

        // cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Open", SqlDbType.VarChar, 40));    //using this way "The variable name '@Open' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure."
        // cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Open", textBox13.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Open", textBox13.Text);          
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@High", textBox14.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Low", textBox15.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Close", textBox16.Text);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();   // Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Open'.
    }

    stocksTableAdapter.Update(database.Stocks); //LINE***added later but still getting "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Open'."
}
```

In the database, a table added called `Stocks`, with 5 columns (`Id, Open, High, Low, Close`). I apologise if I'm missing something obvious, as I'm fairly new to SQL Server. The database is created as a service-based database and there is no value given other than creating `Open, High, Low, Close, Day` columns and defining their inputs as `Decimal(18,4)` for `Open, High, Low, Close` and `Datetime` for `Day` (but this is not deed any value in the code yet)

Comment: If you are checking it by looking at your datagridView then I guess then it's probably in the database but there is a bug in your datagridView.

Comment: Are you able to check the table contents directly to see if the insert worked ?

Comment: I have tied the database.stocks table from the top right datagridview tasks. I have taken it from a code where its design to accept input into datagridview when its running, and then save it to database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Open` and `Close` are [**reserved T-SQL keywords**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx) which you should **NOT** be using as your table and/or column names. Try to use something **more intuitive** for your business case - e.g. `OpenValue` and `CloseValue` or something like that.

If you **insist** on using those names, then you **must** put them in square brackets: `[Open]` and `[Close]`

```
string query = "INSERT INTO dbo.Stocks ([Open], High, Low, [Close], Day) " +
               "VALUES (@Open, @High, @Low, @Close, @Day);"; 

using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
{
    .....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Open", "Value"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be more like this?

```
com.CommandText = (@"INSERT INTO Stock (Prod_ID, Prod_Name, Prod_Cat, Supplier, Cost, Price_1, Price_2, Price_3) VALUES ('"+ProdID.Text+"','"+ProdName.Text+"','"+ProdCat.Text+"','"+ProdSup.Text+"','"+ProdCost.Text+"','"+ProdPrice1.Text+"','"+ProdPrice2.Text+"','"+ProdPrice3.Text+"');"));
```

Just an example...