# C# - How do I save a file path into database based on the file name?

Tags: c#, database, mdf

Here's the flow of what I'm doing:

1) Recorded videos from 3 different ip cameras get automatically saved into a file (C:\Users\sit\Videos\Done).

2) The videos are automatically *(I can't customize the names)* named "Camera 1_live_2018-06-18...", "Camera 2_live_2018-06-18..." & "Camera 3_live_2018-06-18..." based on the camera and date it was recorded on.

3) 
Here is the table that I want to save them into. (I am using a .mdf database on Visual Studio 2017) The 'VIEWS' are namely AudienceView1, AudienceView2 and LecturerView.

[image]

I want to save "C:\Users\sit\Videos\Done\Camera 1_live..." as 'VIDEO_PATH' with 'VIEW' as AudienceView1, "Camera 2_..." = AudienceView2 and "Camera 3_..." = LecturerView. (You get the idea)

What I want to achieve in the end is each time a video stops recording, the file path gets saved into the database with their corresponding 'VIEW'.

I apologize if my explanation is confusing, so please point out if something is unclear. Any help/recommended methods would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Hello, I would post the code that you've attempted first or you will get down voted. Make an attempt, show where its going wrong, then people will help you fix / resolve any issues.

Comment: `System.IO.File` contains functions for moving and coping file, `System.IO.Directory` has code for reading which files are in a directory

Comment: You aren't exactly clear about what your problem is. Are you asking how to write data to a database?

Comment: @PaulF Yes. I want the file path of a saved video to base saved under the 'VIDEO_PATH' of my database.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41540550/inserting-values-into-database-mdf-c-sharp - there will be plenty of tutorials that you can find online. Looking at your table - it looks like you may need to query the Lesson table first to find the primary key to enter as LESSON_ID.